# How to compare the caught exception against standard exceptions in asynchronous task android?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask

I am a beginner in both java and android. I am using asynchronous task in my project to fetch some data from a web service, faced some problems in exception handling. I referred this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739515/android-asynctask-and-error-handling) and I am following the pattern suggested by CommonsWare in this [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/blob/master/15-Internet/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/FeedActivity.java).

I succeeded in catching the exceptions and storing it in an exception variable. I need to compare the caught exception against some standard exceptions  in `onPostExecute` method also I would like to display custom error messages based on that. How can I compare this caught exception against standard exceptions? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `Instanceof` java keyword. It returns true if object instance is of correct type.

```
if(e instanceof SomeStandardException)
```

**Note:** `instanceof` returns true for both exact type and all parent types. So if you use it in a cascading `if-elseif` then put more concrete types at the top and more generic (parent) types at the bottom.

**Note2:** catching generic `Exception` as proposed in the link is a bad practice - you should only catch exceptions that you want to handle. So instead of saving the exceptin, you should catch a concrete exception via `try-catch-catch`, save appropriate flag (boolean field maybe) and then act on this flag.