# Android: Warning when cancelling AsyncTask from doInBackground

Tags: android

I'm having this problem:

I have a main **Activity** that request information for another class, that class gets that information from a web service, so I do that on a **AsyncTask** class. While the data is being loaded, the main **Activity** shows a **ProgressDialog**, I'm handling the back button so when it's pressed I can dismiss the Dialog, but now I want to cancel the **AsyncTask**. I created a static boolean var that is "true" when the back button is pressed, so from the **doInBackground** method from the **AsyncTask** I check if that var is true, if it's true I cancel the **AsyncTask**:

```
@Override protected Void doInBackground(Integer... args) {      
  try {
        ....        
      if ( MainActivity.isDialogCancelled ){
        cancel(true);
        }
        ....
  } catch (Exception e) {
      ....
  } 
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm seeing a **InterruptedException** warning when I cancel the task this way, why is this happening and how I can avoid them? I'm doing something wrong?

These are the warnings:

```
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877): java.lang.InterruptedException
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1272)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:220)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:196)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerCancel(FutureTask.java:294)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:76)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at android.os.AsyncTask.cancel(AsyncTask.java:325)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-24 18:40:50.582: W/AsyncTask(22877):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: catch it. more to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739515/android-asynctask-and-error-handling

Comment: you sure you're doing it at the correct place? Have you read this? Cancelling a task- A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the whole code, but I'm already catching it, but it still shows the warning on the Logcat, I updated the code on the main post showing the try/catch use

Comment: Please don't use the quote style for code or stack traces, use the code button (or 4 spaces at the beginning of the line) instead. Thanks

Comment: @Sergey, I read the paragraph you pasted it, it says that I cant cancel a task at any time... can I cancel a task from the method doInBackground of the class itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully read this one mate. it has a good sample there.

Comment: and here's another one just in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask

Comment: Thanks for the links Sergey! I already read them, but I think the issue here is that I'm trying to cancel the task from the method doInbackground, I'm doing that because the Dialog is showed from another class outside the AsyncTask, so I can't do AsyncTask.cancel() when Back is pressed, for that reason I check in the method doInBackground for a static var that knows if the user cancelled or no the Dialog. I think that checking only that static var and not cancelling the task will work for what I'm doing.

Comment: Glad to help and glad you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `asyncTask.cancel(true);` from onPause()??

Comment: Because sometimes you want to cancel the download or any long lasting task using a cancel button or the Back button of an android device.

Comment: Right, this issue is happening when I try to cancel the task when the Back button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Like any other `Thread`, you must wrap it with try/catch and catch `InterruptedException`.

Moreover, `AsyncTask` has a function `cancel(boolean)`, use it instead of what you did ,and check if it's canceled using `isCacneled()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other answers here are correct but just to try to explain a bit more thoroughly:

It's **not** good practice to be calling back to a method of your `Activity` from your `AsyncTask` in order to check whether you should cancel or not.

The correct way (as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)):

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking `cancel(boolean)`. Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to `isCancelled()` to return true. After invoking this method, `onCancelled(Object)`, instead of `onPostExecute(Object)` will be invoked after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. **To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])`**, if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

(bolding mine)

So, you have the right basic idea in your code, but instead of setting something on your `Activity`, call the `cancel()` method of the AsyncTask when you want to cancel it. This changes the return value of the `isCancelled()` method. Then, inside your `doInBackground()` method you should check the `isCancelled()` value and choose your behavior based on the result.

And yes, while it's probably not ideal, I have seen functioning code which calls `cancel(true);` from inside the `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel(false) just sets the cancel flag of asynctask. If you call cancel(true) it sets the cancel flag of asynctask and also interrupts the background thread that asynctask runs on. That is where the interruptedException can come from.