# Managing exception in AsyncTask

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I have this code:

```
 public void remote(final Backup backup) {
        local(backup);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BackupSendInfo sendInfo = new BackupSendInfo()
                        .setFile(getLastBackup()) // <---
                        .setFileName(getBackupName(backup))
                        .setBackup(backup)
                        .setDeviceId(device)
                        .setApp(config.getAppName());
                fileSender.send(sendInfo);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is `getLastBackup` method signature:

```
private File getLastBackup() throws BackupException;
```

As you can see, it throws `BackupException`, but I can't add `throws BackuPException` delcaration in `remote` method signature, because it is in another thread.

How should I manage this situation? **I want `remote` method to throws BackupException**

Comment: Catch the exception inside asynctask method and throw it.

Comment: I can`t. If I re-throw it inside of catch in AsyncTask, I get the same error: the exception has to be catched.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6312491/4596556

Comment: Thanks. I like the `ExceptionAsyncTask` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Maybe, it is not the best one.

I get the `lastBackup` outside AsyncTask, this way I can declare `throws BackupException`.

```
 public void remote(final Backup backup) throws BackupException {
        local(backup);
        final File lastBackup = getLastBackup();
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BackupSendInfo sendInfo = new BackupSendInfo()
                        .setFile(lastBackup)
                        .setFileName(getBackupName(backup))
                        .setBackup(backup)
                        .setDeviceId("Desconocido") //TODO leer dispositivo del fichero deviceName
                        .setApp(config.getAppName());
                fileSender.send(sendInfo);
            }
        });
    }
```